# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type', What does this mean in pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo, indexed

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


# Sets
model.k = pyo.RangeSet(136)
model.i = pyo.Set(initialize = [1,2,3,4])
model.n = pyo.Set(model.i,initialize = {1:[1,2,3],2:[1,2,3,4,5],3:[1,2,3],4:[1,2]})

def set_init(model):
    return [(i,n) for i in model.i for n in model.n[i]]
model.x = pyo.Set(dimen = 2,initialize = set_init)

#Param
model.t = pyo.Param(model.k,initialize = np.arange(0, 68, 0.5).tolist())
model.tauB = pyo.Param(model.x)

#Var
model.Sb = pyo.Var(model.k,model.x,within=pyo.Binary)
model.Db = pyo.Var(model.x,domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def rule3(model,i,n):
    return model.Db[i,n]>=sum(model.Sb[k,i,n]*model.t[k] for k in model.k) - model.tauB[i,n]
model.objconst = pyo.Constraint(model.i,model.n[i],rule=rule3)
```

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint objconst with
index (1, 1): AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute
'is_expression_type'

ERROR: Constructing component 'objconst' from data=None failed:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

What is the correct way to use this indexed set model.x to build the constraint?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  From the code you provide above, I get an error that `i` is not defined in your constraint construction, which is accurate.  So you might have `i` defined somewhere else in your code?.  Specifically, `i` is not defined in:
`pyo.Constraint(model.i,model.n[i],rule=rule3`

Comment: Also...  you are attempting to index `Sb` and `Db` in `rule3` using incorrect indices relative to what you defined them with... ???

Comment: `Sb` and `Db` are indexed with `model.x` which includes the index i and n. I created this auxiliary set `model.x` , so I can use the indexed set n for the modelling.

Comment: Ok, you are correct there.  I misread.  See solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going.  Made several tweaks.  You should use `model.x` for creating your last constraint as you cannot reference the value `i` in the rule statement.  Also, I re-worked your `k` values.  This compiles.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

k_data = { idx:item for idx, item in enumerate(np.arange(0, 68, 0.5))}


# Sets
model.k = pyo.Set(initialize=k_data.keys())
model.i = pyo.Set(initialize = [1,2,3,4])
model.n = pyo.Set(model.i,initialize = {1:[1,2,3],2:[1,2,3,4,5],3:[1,2,3],4:[1,2]})

def set_init(model):
    return [(i,n) for i in model.i for n in model.n[i]]
model.x = pyo.Set(dimen = 2,initialize = set_init)

#Param
model.t = pyo.Param(model.k,initialize = k_data)
model.tauB = pyo.Param(model.x, initialize = 0)  # <-- need some values for this

#Var
model.Sb = pyo.Var(model.k,model.x,within=pyo.Binary)
model.Db = pyo.Var(model.x,domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def rule3(model,i,n):
    return model.Db[i,n]>=sum(model.Sb[k,i,n]*model.t[k] for k in model.k) - model.tauB[i,n]
model.objconst = pyo.Constraint(model.x,rule=rule3)
```